# Hw to get rid of ORA-01008

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

While trying to code in VS 2019 (making utility to select data from Oracle DB) I got stuck.

1. I created DataSet with TableAdapter to it [Pic0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOiT0.jpg)
2. In a query I must enter value for APPLICATION_NUMBER field, and when I "Execute Query" everything works fine and I get result  (see Pic1)[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqcQX.jpg)
3. But when I try to "Preview Data", I got error "ORA-01008: not all variables bound"
   [(see Pic2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c33OL.jpg)

Just for info: it is Oracle 9i I am trying to connect to, I am using .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB because if I use .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle it says "Connections to this server version are no longer supported".

Would appreciate much any useful info.

I tried to replace :PARAM2 with '&PARAM2' but with no luck.

Comment: This probably isn't a lot of help resolving your issue, but Oracle 9i has been out of support for over 20 years. Odds are any current day programming framework isn't going to work entirely as expected (if at all) with something that old.

Comment: Looks odd that the second example is not prompting for PARAM2 but for APPLICATION_NUMBER.  Might be a bug in the Preview Data facility